# angular-ui template not loading

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I am having an issue with angular-ui-router. I'm not getting any errors and still I'm not able to see partials template. Moreover, it's not redirecting to `'/'` as well as if I change to `'/home'`, its not working.

Below is piece of my code,

```
angular.module('SampleApp', ['ui.router']).config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

$stateProvider

           .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'partials/partial-home.html'
    })


    .state('about', {
        // about page      
    });});
```

here is the html code of main page

```
<div id="container">
<div id="header">
    <img src="images/logo.png" height="40" />
    <div id="header_left">
        <img src="images/browse.png" /><a href="#" ng-click="categories()">Categories</a>

    </div>
    <div id="categories_menu"><p><a href="">Mobiles</a></p><p><a href="">Tablets</a></p>
        </div>
    <div id="search">
        <input type="text" id="searchbox" name="searchbox" placeholder="Search" />
        <input type="submit" id="inputsearchbox" name="inputsearchbox" value="" />
    </div>
</div>

 <div ui-view></div></div>
```

and my partial page is

```
<div class="wrapperwide">
    <div class="home-featured card"></div>
    <a target="_blank" href="#" class="home-sidebox card">test </a>
</div>
```

Could someone please help me out. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Please show your html.

Comment: Do you have `ng-app='SampleApp'` somewhere in your code?

Comment: yes i have beside html like this :<html lang="en" ng-app='SampleApp'>

Comment: A created jsfiddle ad it works, http://jsfiddle.net/michal_taborowski/bos3x697/

Comment: sorry i am new to angular, i tried angular 1.2.1 version and ui-route v1.2.0rc1 now i am getting error : [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.1/$injector/modulerr?p0=SampleApp&p1=%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.1%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3Dui.router%26p1%3D%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.2.1%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253Dui.router

Comment: Do you have angular-ui-router.js script included in your page?

Comment: i got the output, In controller which i included in page had angular.module('SampleApp',[])..i removed [] and got the output..